# Replace a String in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace

I am Trying to replace a substring in a sentence. 
Example: Name Id = Name_ID
Date of Birth = Date_of_Birth
Admission Type = Admission_Type
I have tried the below code
But it does not seem to work.

```
line = "Name Name Id Username Date of Birth Admission Type"
line.replace("Name Id","Name_ID",1)
line.replace("Date of Birth","Date_of_Birth")
line.replace("Admission Type","Admission_Type"



Expected Output:
line = "Name Name_Id Username Date_of_Birth Admission_Type"

My code Output:
line = "Name Name Id Username Date of Birth Admission Type"
```

Comment: You have to reassign the replaced string: `line = line.replace(...`

Comment: Please read the documentation. `replace` does not mutate the string. You have to reassign it like this: `line = line.replace(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replace()` does not mutate the string you provide to it. You need to reassign `line` to the string that is returned by `replace()`:

```
line = "Name Name Id Username Date of Birth Admission Type"
line = line.replace("Name Id","Name_ID",1)
line = line.replace("Date of Birth","Date_of_Birth")
line = line.replace("Admission Type","Admission_Type"
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

> **string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])**
>   Return a copy of string s with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument maxreplace is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced